# Como obter conteúdo do PDF gerado pelo Rotativa?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, pdf

Estou utilizando o Rotativa para a geração de PDF a partir de um .cshtml
Consigo fazer o download do arquivo pela aplicação corretamente utilizando o comando abaixo:

```
DadosConvite convidado = new DadosConvite(); 
convidado.nome = "teste";
return new Rotativa.ViewAsPdf("ConvitePDF", convidado) { FileName = "Convite.pdf"};
```

Porém estou precisando enviar esse PDF por email, ao invés de apenas disponibilizar o download do mesmo para o usuário.

Como posso obter o conteúdo (byte[]) deste PDF para ser anexado ao email?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`ViewAsPdf` tem um parâmetro a mais chamado `SaveOnServerPath`, em que você passa o caminho a ser salvo em disco:

```
var myPDF = new ViewAsPdf("ConvitePDF")
{
    FileName = "Convite.pdf",
    PageSize = Size.A4,
    SaveOnServerPath = caminho // preecha caminho com o diretório a ser salvo
};

// Reabra o arquivo aqui e envie como e-mail

return View("Index"); // Use o redirect normal e retorne para alguma View.
```

Ou então, melhor ainda, você usa o método `BuildPdf` e recupera um array de bytes:

```
var pdfResult = new ActionAsPdf("ActionParaFazerOConvite", new { name = "Convite" }) 
                                                 { FileName = "Convite.pdf" };

var arrayDeBytes = pdfResult.BuildPdf(this.ControllerContext);
```